# T9 / multitap keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm trying to implement a T9/Multitap Keyboard. The aim is to be able to switch between the two mods.

My problem is that, in my keyboard layout, i have to put the codes of each key :

example : `<key android:codes="[97,98,99]" android:keyLabel="abc"/>`

Problem :
If i use comma separated values like in the example, the keyboard automatically works as a multitap and wait one second before allow you to type 2 times the same key. I can't find how to avoid this behavior.

Does one of you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to avoid this behavior"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Back to this problem after a long breack...
The issue is that if I do :
<key android:codes="[97,98,99]" android:keyLabel="abc"/>
and try to write "cab" by pressing 3 times "abc", my keyboard catch only one call of "abc" and will print "a" (as "a" is the only one among "a", "b" and "c" to be in the dictionary).